# zapier is unable to send challenge value to enable slack event api

Tags: slack, verification, zapier

I'm using zapier with slack and want to catch an event when `message_replied` event was created as referred [here](https://api.slack.com/events/message/message_replied).

To use event API, it needs [URL verification](https://api.slack.com/events/url_verification), which is unable on zapier webhook catching. The following error occurs repeatedly; Request URL Your URL didn't respond with the value of the `challenge` parameter.

Are there any workarounds?
I'd really appreciate any help you can provide.

some related informations:

- app used in zapier : Webhooks by Zapier
- Event in zapier : Catch Hook
- feature used in slack bot : Event Subscriptions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not currently possible. "Webhooks by Zapier" will only respond with the default "success" response because it's intended to be used with any incoming webhook. For that product, there's not special cases for any particular service.

If you're trying to integration with the Slack Events API (something I implemented at Zapier), then I recommend writing your own web service to catch Slack hooks, do business logic, and then send relevant webhooks onto Zapier as needed. This will afford you much more control over the process.

Comment: Thanks, I've tried to implement app on heroku to catch this webhook and bypassed needed  information to heroku. It worked.